# SendGrid email read confirmation

Tags: sendgrid, email-confirmation

I want to collect information about how many emails that I have sent, has been read. I want to use method where I will put image in email and once the image gets rendered I can catch that event. I know this is not hundred percent reliable.

I am using a SendGrid for sending my emails. I was wondering does SendGrid provides service like this?

I was looking through SendGrid documentation but was not able to find what I need.

Comment: SendGrid will not force your email content, so if you want to put in an image then put one in. What you *may* find, is that they might block your use if you are using it for spammy emails... can't confirm that though. I am pretty sure they have reporting tools on their sites (from what I remember), not sure if they have any "read" data though

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to use the [Open Tracking](http://sendgrid.com/docs/Apps/open_tracking.html) app. You can also enable, disable, and configure this app via the web API or SMTP API headers.